# MySQL. Удаление записи, если при попытке обновления возникла ошибка 'Duplicate entry'

Tags: mysql

Собственно задача: Нужно при неудачной попытке обновления, вследствии совпадения по уникальным ключам, удалять запись, обновить которую не получилось.

Пока решил на части задач, где обновление идет по первичному ключу, с помощью `PHP` так:

```
if(!mysql_query("UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id = '{$id}'")) {

     if(stripos(mysql_error(), 'Duplicate entry') !== false) {

          mysql_query("DELETE FROM ... WHERE id = '{$id}'");

     }

}
```

Получается громоздко. Да и ключ известен не всегда. Можно ли решить средствами `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1):

> Да и ключ известен не всегда

а по какому условию обновление поля тогда будет и удаление тоже?

так не короче, но читабильней и правильней

```
try
{
 mysql_query("UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id = '{$id}'")
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
 if ($ex->getCode() == 1062)
 {
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM ... WHERE id = '{$id}'");
 }
}
```